# Content type not working in struts

Tags: struts, struts-1, struts-validation, struts1

This is written in my validate method. The check for size and empty  upload is working but content type is not, am i missing something ?

```
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

    if(file1.getFileSize()==0)
    {
    errors.add("file1", new ActionMessage("error.file.required"));
    }
    else if(!file1.getContentType().equals("audio/mpeg"));
    {
    errors.add("file1",new ActionMessage("error.file.type"));
    }
    if(file1.getFileSize()>51200)
    {
    errors.add("file1",new ActionMessage("error.file.size"));
    }

    return errors;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your else if condition statement is missing because of ";" sign as the following :

```
else if(!file1.getContentType().equals("audio/mpeg"));
```

It should be as the following :

```
else if(!file1.getContentType().equals("audio/mpeg"))
```

Comment: ';' is just a silly mistake that happened here but "audio/mpeg" is not accepting the mp3 files. i figured it out am providing my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

done with:

```
else if(!file1.getContentType().equals("audio/mp3")) { ---- }
```

I checked the type of the the fileuploaded by: `String ctype = file1.getContentType();` without puting any validation (i.e upload any file) and printed it on the jsp page. From there i came to know that its audio/mp3. Now all validations are working. /

Comment: I tried it with Chrome only so content type(audio/mpeg) may work with other browsers